# Get Build Quality List

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I have a custom build that deploys code, part of the deploy process I need to specify the build quality. Currently I have to type in the quality, such as "Ready for Deployment". I want to add a custom process parameter dropdown that contains all the build qualities already setup for the project.

Initially I started to create a custom activity to get the build qualities. TFS has a method to do this already using:

```
buildServer.GetBuildQualities(teamProjectName)
```

However, the custom activity requires the TeamProjectName to be passed in. This is where I get confused, I don't understand how to pass this argument in.

We have lots of projects and I want to use the same build definition for all of them, so I can't hardcode the team project name.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `BuildDetail` variable (of type [`IBuildDetail`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.client.ibuilddetail.aspx)) in the Workflow. This has a `TeamProject` property that contains the name of the team project for the current build workflow that is running.

You should add a `String` input argument to your activity and set the value in the XAML designer to `BuildDetail.TeamProject` so that it is passed in.

Comment: Well... the problem I ran into with that, is the process parameters load before the build executes. So I need a way to inject the team project name when queuing the build, not executing it.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to using a custom activity, the `BuildDetail.Quality` can be manipulated using simple assignments. For example you can put the sequence below in the `Finally` clause of the `Try Compile and Test` element:

```
<Sequence DisplayName="Set Build Quality" >
<If Condition="[BuildDetail.CompilationStatus = BuildPhaseStatus.Succeeded]" DisplayName="BuildDetail.CompilationStatus = BuildPhaseStatus.Succeeded" >
  <If.Then>
    <Assign DisplayName="Assign Build Quality Ready">
      <Assign.To>
        <OutArgument x:TypeArguments="x:String">[BuildDetail.Quality]</OutArgument>
      </Assign.To>
      <Assign.Value>
        <InArgument x:TypeArguments="x:String">["Ready for Initial Test"]</InArgument>
      </Assign.Value>
    </Assign>
  </If.Then>
  <If.Else>
    <Assign DisplayName="Assign Build Quality Under Investigation">
      <Assign.To>
        <OutArgument x:TypeArguments="x:String">[BuildDetail.Quality]</OutArgument>
      </Assign.To>
      <Assign.Value>
        <InArgument x:TypeArguments="x:String">Under Investigation</InArgument>
      </Assign.Value>
    </Assign>
  </If.Else>
</If>
</Sequence>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I'm looking for a way to add a dropdown to the custom process parameters (the parameters tab when queuing a new build). So that users can choose the build quality they want to promote to another environment.